# Limit storage per user on minio

Tags: storage, minio, object-storage

I am setting up minio for the first time and I wonder if there is a way to limit the storage of each user, for exemple the users gets 50GB max to create buckets and store the files.

In the docs I only found stuff about limit the bucket size but not the user storage size.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the quota on the bucket
https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/reference/minio-mc-admin/mc-admin-bucket-quota.html?highlight=hard%20quota#mc.admin.bucket.quota.-hard
You can create a specific user to associate with the bucket. This can be done from the console or CLI.